# Can someone help clarify my confusion about syncdb and import loops, 'Do you have to be explicit on imports?'

Tags: python, django, django-syncdb

I have been having a difficult time building the database with syncdb on Python2.5.
I think that some of this issue is because of the use of wildcard* for importing forum.models it seems to be creating a loop.

```
>>> import settings  
>>> from forum.managers import QuestionManager, TagManager, AnswerManager, VoteManager, FlaggedItemManager, ReputeManager, AwardManager  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "/home/username/webapps/username/sousvide_app/forum/managers.py", line 6, in <module>  
    from forum.models import *  
  File "/home/username/webapps/username/sousvide_app/forum/models.py", line 18, in <module>  
    from forum.managers import QuestionManager, TagManager, AnswerManager, VoteManager, FlaggedItemManager, ReputeManager, AwardManager  
ImportError: cannot import name QuestionManager  
>>> from forum.models import Question, Tag  
>>> from forum.managers import QuestionManager, TagManager, AnswerManager, VoteManager, FlaggedItemManager, ReputeManager, AwardManager  
>>> import sys, pprint  
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)  
['/home/username/webapps/username/sousvide_app',  
 '/home/username/webapps/username/lib/python2.5',  
 '/home/username/lib/python2.5/markdown2-1.0.1.16-py2.5.egg',  
 '/home/username/lib/python2.5/html5lib-0.11.1-py2.5.egg',  
 '/home/username/lib/python2.5',  
 '/usr/local/lib/python25.zip',  
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.5',  
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/plat-linux2',  
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/lib-tk',  
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload',  
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages',  
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL']  
>>> from settings import INSTALLED_APPS  
>>> pprint.pprint(INSTALLED_APPS)  
('sousvide_app.forum',  
 'django.contrib.auth',  
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',  
 'django.contrib.sessions',  
 'django.contrib.sites',  
 'django.contrib.admin',  
 'django.contrib.humanize',  
 'django_authopenid')
```

I had the same issue on another install that I was able to fix by explicitly importing the managers from forum.managers .
As you can see, if I load Question and Tag models into the namespace I'm able to import the managers in the shell.

I made the from forum.models import * explicit:
from forum.models import Question, Tag

However, I'm still not able to syncdb. When I try to output the SQL the APP can't be found.
$ python2.5 manage.py sql forum
Error: App with label forum could not be found. Are you sure your INSTALLED_APPS setting is correct?

Can anyone give me an idea what is going wrong?
Is there something about Python2.5 that could contribute to this error?

Comment: I am suddenly the same error.  Hmph.

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to be using `global_settings.py` or `local_settings.py` in addition to `settings.py`?

The proper way to import Django's settings is to use the decoupled object `from django.conf import settings`, NOT to `import settings`.  See the doc page about it here: [Using settings in Python code](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code)

I can't say for certain if that's the fix to your problem, but it's a step in the right direction to make sure your settings are being loaded properly if you say your issue is apps not showing up in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I am using local_settings.py that imports webhost_settings.py, which contains the INSTALLED_APPS tuple because it needs to include  app_name.forum . I tried to move INSTALLED_APPS to settings.py and I still can't syncdb.